# Compiler Error on using Braced Initialisation C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, clang, c++17

The following error is received while using empty braces to initialise variables:

```
error: expected ';' at end of declaration
    int b{};
         ^
         ;
```

The code being used is:

```cpp
#include<iostream>

int main(){
    int a{};
    std::cout<<"hello"<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using the latest version of Microsoft VS Code on an M1 based Macbook Air. Extensions being used are C/C++ Intellisense and Code Runner.

Same error is displayed when running the file in terminal.

The `tasks.json` file looks like this:

```java
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "clang++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-std=c++17",
                "-stdlib=libc++",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build"
        },
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: clang++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: /usr/bin/clang++"
        }
    ]
  }
```

`int a={4};` works fine while `int a={};` throws an error `error: scalar initializer cannot be empty`

As a person who is habituated of using braced initialisation, this issue is giving me quite some trouble. Any fix for this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: You either use an outdated compiler, or your compiler defaults to C++98 (try adding `-std=c++??` (`??` = 11/14/17/20/...).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat If you are talking about the `tasks.json` file, then it is already set to `-std=c++17`. If not, then sorry but can you elaborate a bit more.

Comment: Not sure why that's not working. Does it work if you compile from the terminal?

Comment: Nope, same error pops up in the terminal too.

Comment: *then it is already set to -std=c++17* -- The issue is that you're saying "it is already set...", but where is the proof that the line in the JSON file has any effect?  There is an `args` node that does not have that line.  You would also assume that *none* of those other options are taking effect, not just `-std=c++17`.

Comment: @cynicalish When you compiled in the terminal, did you add `-std=c++17`?

Comment: It looks like your `tasks.json` has two tasks, one called "shell" that has `-std=c++17` as an argument and one called "cppbuild" that does not and which apparently has "isDefault" set to `true`. Is it possible you're building with the latter instead of the former?

Comment: @NathanPierson Adding `-std=c++17` to the `cppbuild` has no effect
@HolyBlackCat No I didn't. After adding `-std=c++17` in the terminal, the file worked! Any ideas on how to do the same for VS Code? I tried changing the `Cpp Standard` in extension settings to `c++17` but it has no effect.

Comment: @cynicalish -- If you can't get `-std=c++17` to be recognized, then as I stated, none of your options are taking effect, not just `-std=c++17`.  So it is much more than getting `-std=c++17` to work correctly -- something is fundamentally missing, wrong, or not set up correctly in your compiler/IDE tools.